# Sending values through links

Tags: html, url

Here is the situation: I have 2 pages.

What I want is to have a number of text links(`<a href="">`) on page 1 all directing to page 2, but I want each link to send a different value.

On page 2 I want to show that value like this:

> Hello you clicked {value}

Another point to take into account is that I can't use any php in this situation, just html.

Answer (score 4):

Can you use any scripting?  Something like Javascript.  If you can, then pass the values along in the query string (just add a "?ValueName=Value") to the end of your links.  Then on the target page retrieve the query string value.  The following site shows how to parse it out: [Parsing the Query String](http://adamv.com/dev/javascript/querystring).

Here's the Javascript code you would need:

```
var qs = new Querystring();
var v1 = qs.get("ValueName")
```

From there you should be able to work with the passed value.

Comment: that link appears to be broken now

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can get it. Say, you're trying to get the querystring value from this url:  http://foo.com/default.html?foo=bar

```
var tabvalue = getQueryVariable("foo"); 

function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var vars = query.split("&");
for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++)
{
var pair = vars[i].split("=");
if (pair[0] == variable)
{
return pair[1];
}
}
}
```

** Not 100% certain if my JS code here is correct, as I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this using HTML Anchors.

http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp

Answer (score 0):

Append your data to the HREF tag of your links ad use javascript on second page to parse the URL and display wathever you want

http://java-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/how_to_get_url_parts_in_javascript

It's not clean, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use **document.location.search** and **split()**

```
http://www.example.com/example.html?argument=value

var queryString = document.location.search();
var parts = queryString.split('=');
document.write(parts[0]);  // The argument name
document.write(parts[1]);  // The value
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Well this is pretty basic with javascript, but if you want more of this and more advanced stuff you should really look into php for instance. Using php it's easy to get variables from one page to another, here's an example:

the url:

```
localhost/index.php?myvar=Hello World
```

You can then access myvar in index.php using this bit of code:

```
$myvar =$_GET['myvar'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for all your replies, i'll take a look if i can find a way to use the scripts.
It's really annoying since i have to work around a CMS, because in the CMS, all pages are created with a Wysiwyg editor which tend to filter out unrecognized tags/scripts.

Edit: Ok it seems that the damn wysiwyg editor only recognizes html tags... (as expected)

Answer (score 0):

Using php

```
<?

$passthis = "See you on the other side";

echo '<form action="whereyouwantittogo.php" target="_blank" method="post">'.
'<input type="text" name="passthis1" value="'.
$passthis .' " /> '.
'<button type="Submit" value="Submit" >Submit</button>'.
'</form>';

?>
```

The script for the page you would like to pass the info to:

```
<?

$thispassed = $_POST['passthis1'];

echo '<textarea>'. $thispassed .'</textarea>';
echo $thispassed;

?>
```

Use this two codes on seperate pages with the latter at whereyouwantittogo.php and you should be in business.